# How do I to populate one table with the results of a query from a different table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have created a query which works and delivers what I want,however it will not execute within a batch file.How can I populate another table with the results of the successfully executed query?

Here is my query

```
select  

isnull (start_charge.account,'No account at start') Start_charge_account
,Finish_charge.account start_charge_account   
,case when start_charge.account is null then finish_charge.account else       start_charge.account end "account" 
,isnull (start_charge.Branch,99999999999) Start_charge_Branch
,Finish_charge.Branch Finish_charge_Branch
,case when start_charge.branch is null then finish_charge.branch else  start_charge.branch end " branch"
,isnull (start_charge. site_number,99999999999) Start_charge_site_number
,Finish_charge. site_number Finish_charge_site_number
,case when start_charge.site_number is null then finish_charge.site_number else start_charge.site_number end "site_number"
,isnull (start_charge. service_code, 'No account at start') Start_charge_service_code
,Finish_charge. service_code finish_charge_service_code
,isnull (start_charge. item_code,'No account at start') Start_charge_item_code
,Finish_charge. item_code finish_charge_item_code
,isnull (start_charge. why_code, 'No account at start') Start_charge_why_code
,Finish_charge. why_code finish_charge_why_code
,isnull (start_charge. why_type, 'No account at start') Start_charge_why_type
,Finish_charge. why_type finish_charge_why_type

,Start_charge.Start_charge
,isnull(Finish_charge.Finish_charge,0) Finish_charge
,isnull(Start_charge.Start_charge,0)-isnull(Finish_charge.Finish_charge,0) Variance


from

(
select

account
,branch
,site_number
,service_code
,item_code
,why_code
,why_type
,sum(charge)
 "Start_Charge"

from

cannon_commercial

where

1=1
and record_type = 'PS'
and period = ' 02/07/2013'

group by

account
,branch
,site_number
,service_code
,item_code
,why_code
,why_type
) start_charge 



    full outer join 



( select

account
,branch
,site_number
,service_code
,item_code
,why_code
,why_type
,concat(account,site_number) "account - site"
,ISNULL(sum(charge),0) "Finish_Charge"

from

cannon_commercial

where

1=1
and record_type= 'PS'
and period = ' 04/06/2013'

group by

account
,branch
,site_number
,service_code
,item_code
,why_code
,why_type
)
Finish_charge

on  Start_charge.Account = Finish_charge.Account
and Start_charge.Branch = Finish_charge.Branch
and Start_charge.site_number = Finish_charge.site_number
and Start_charge.item_code = Finish_charge.item_code
and Start_charge.service_code = Finish_charge.service_code
and Start_charge.why_code = Finish_charge.why_code
and Start_charge.why_type = Finish_charge.why_type
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of dealing with it:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable AS
  (SELECT ... )
```

will create a new table with the results of your query.

```
INSERT INTO mytable (field1, field2, ...)
  (SELECT ... )
```

will insert the results of your query into an existing table.  You'll need to make sure that the column list matches, naturally.  If the query returns column list matching your existing table exactly, then you don't need to specify the field list and your statement becomes simply

```
INSERT INTO mytable (SELECT ... )
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes u can populate an existing table which is having same number of columns and datatype as returned by your query.

Your query can be

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME

(
select  

isnull (start_charge.account,'No account at start') Start_charge_account
,Finish_charge.account start_charge_account   
,case when start_charge.account is null then finish_charge.account else       start_charge.account end "account" 
,isnull (start_charge.Branch,99999999999) Start_charge_Branch
,Finish_charge.Branch Finish_charge_Branch
,case when start_charge.branch is null then finish_charge.branch else  start_charge.branch end " branch"
,isnull (start_charge. site_number,99999999999) Start_charge_site_number
,Finish_charge. site_number Finish_charge_site_number
,case when start_charge.site_number is null then finish_charge.site_number else start_charge.site_number end "site_number"
,isnull (start_charge. service_code, 'No account at start') Start_charge_service_code
,Finish_charge. service_code finish_charge_service_code
,isnull (start_charge. item_code,'No account at start') Start_charge_item_code
,Finish_charge. item_code finish_charge_item_code
,isnull (start_charge. why_code, 'No account at start') Start_charge_why_code
,Finish_charge. why_code finish_charge_why_code
,isnull (start_charge. why_type, 'No account at start') Start_charge_why_type
,Finish_charge. why_type finish_charge_why_type

,Start_charge.Start_charge
,isnull(Finish_charge.Finish_charge,0) Finish_charge
,isnull(Start_charge.Start_charge,0)-isnull(Finish_charge.Finish_charge,0) Variance


from

(
select

account
,branch
,site_number
,service_code
,item_code
,why_code
,why_type
,sum(charge)
 "Start_Charge"

from

cannon_commercial

where

1=1
and record_type = 'PS'
and period = ' 02/07/2013'

group by

account
,branch
,site_number
,service_code
,item_code
,why_code
,why_type
) start_charge 



    full outer join 



( select

account
,branch
,site_number
,service_code
,item_code
,why_code
,why_type
,concat(account,site_number) "account - site"
,ISNULL(sum(charge),0) "Finish_Charge"

from

cannon_commercial

where

1=1
and record_type= 'PS'
and period = ' 04/06/2013'

group by

account
,branch
,site_number
,service_code
,item_code
,why_code
,why_type
)
Finish_charge

on  Start_charge.Account = Finish_charge.Account
and Start_charge.Branch = Finish_charge.Branch
and Start_charge.site_number = Finish_charge.site_number
and Start_charge.item_code = Finish_charge.item_code
and Start_charge.service_code = Finish_charge.service_code
and Start_charge.why_code = Finish_charge.why_code
and Start_charge.why_type = Finish_charge.why_type
)
```

Make sure the table TABLE_NAME already exists and has columns with same datatype as returned by your query.